# How to use Facebook graph api as myself instead of external app, to query friend's data?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that in the API users must allow the app permissions to use their specific user data.

But as a user, I have friends which have their own likes. Is there a possible way to query another user or my friend's profile (using their user id) to get a list of their likes via the Graph API.

Ie. because they've decided to friend me, they've given me their permission on a user basis to access their data in Facebook, so can I query this via the graph api as myself instead of an external app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

What is visible/accessible to you as a user on facebook.com or in their official apps, has litte correlation to what you can see via API.

If you want to access anyone’s likes via API – then they have to login to your app first, and grant it appropriate permission.